# Gradle execute task while another task is running

Tags: gradle, integration-testing

I'm working in a spring boot project to automate integration tests with gradle. I started working recently in a new enterprise, and my colleagues run integration tests as follows:
In the build.gradle file there is an `integrationTest` task

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath = test.output + main.output + compileClasspath
            runtimeClasspath = test.output + main.output + runtimeClasspath
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    mapstruct
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs = [
            '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'
    ]
}

test {
    ignoreFailures = true
}

task integrationTest(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

After launching the task the application starts running in a designated port, then they open postman, import a collection and run the tests.

My job is to find a way to skip the extra clicks, i.e. run the postman collections automatically.
The first idea was to use the [postman-runner gradle plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.michaelruocco/gradle-postman-runner/0.1.2) but I cannot add it to the project due to connectivity issues of enterprise computers.
The second idea which I am currently working on, is to run newman on a powershell script and save the output.

**The problem** is that in gradle you can execute a task once another task is finished, but the `integrationTest` task never finishes. It launches the application in a port and keeps listening for requests. Is there a way to run the other task, which executes the powershell script, after the application has started running on the port and while it is waiting for requests ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:** By design, it is **not possible** in Gradle to execute a task while another task is still running.

---

However, there might still be a solution for your problem. A task in Gradle is just a concept of something that needs to be done as a part of your build. But it does not necessarily represent a single process. Gradle might run a process using two tasks, one to `start` the process and another one to `stop` the process. The following Gradle "pseudo-code" shows an example of this idea.

```
def process

task start {
    doFirst {
        process = startProcess()
    }
    finalizedBy 'stop'
}

task stop {
    dependsOn 'start'
    doFirst {
        process.stop()
    }
}
```

This example even uses Gradle functionality to ensure that each time `start` is executed, `stop` will be executed later on and vice-versa. The [Gradle Docker plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin) uses a similar concept with its task types `DockerStartContainer` and `DockerStopContainer`.

Regarding your use case, you could use one task to start the application listening to a port, another task that runs the actual tests (using Postman) and another task that stops the application once the tests are finished:

```
task startApp {
    doFirst {
        println 'Starting app'
    }
    finalizedBy 'stopApp'
}

task integrationTest {
    doFirst {
        println 'Running integration tests'
    }
    dependsOn 'startApp'
    finalizedBy 'stopApp'
}

task stopApp {
    doFirst {
        println 'Stopping app'
    }
    dependsOn 'startApp'
}
```

This second example is a valid `build.gradle` file that may be used as a template. When running `gradle integrationTest`, you will see that the tasks are executed in the correct order. Now all that is missing is the actual functionality of the tasks. Sadly, the [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task type provided by Gradle does not support this kind of async execution, so you might need a third-party plugin or  create your own task type (maybe based on [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)). You might even wrap your application in a Docker container and use the plugin mentioned above.